# Is Sanskrit a normal Language or It is a must to know language to reach god?

Tags: sanskrit

Can Sanskrit be simply treated as a language the one which is used for communication or It is a must to know language to reach god.

Comment: Sanskrit is simply a language. But Brahman which exists as sound (Vedas) is more than a language.

Comment: what do you mean by 'more than language status'? unclear what you are asking.

Comment: more than language status means I mean like It is the most important Language that one must know to reach god or It is like most most important to be learnt like that.

Comment: Thank you Naryama Sharma ,But I dont understand your 2nd line " But Brahman which exists as sound (Vedas) is more than a language"

Comment: In common terms, Brahman means god. That Brahman exists as sound is Vedas.

Comment: oh ok thank you for your explanation Naryana Sharma ji .Thank you.

Comment: Please mention my name in comment after putting @ symbol, then only I  get notifications

Comment: oh ok Since I am new here I did not know ,thank you @Narayana Sharma

Comment: How is this related to Hinduism? Looks like language specific question.

Comment: It is related here I mean the God as the Primordial Chief(Lord Vishnu) ,for me there is no real god  other than Lord Vishnu. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: Currently your question is only this "What is the importance of Sanskrit? Do we need to learn it to reach god? " which rounds back to importance of Sanskrit language only. It's a language question. Pure language questions are off-topic for the site.

Comment: You may revise your question like "Is knowing Sanskrit an essential to reach the god?" Or "Do one must know Sanskrit to reach the god?" Or "Is it possible to reach the God without knowing Sanskrit?" And I think answer would be Yes since Sanskrit is necessary to understand and interpret Shashtra, however one can follow Jnana, Bhakti etc marga to reach the God without knowing Sanskrit (The true concept and/or preaching of Guru is recommended though).

Comment: @Pandya It is a duplicate and importance of Sanskrit is already discussed in that question. You also cited it in an answer. Don't you remember it?

Comment: Can you define the meaning of "to reach the God".

Comment: to reach god means to attain liberation from birth and death cycle